# Isotope- fitColumns with height auto on items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

My situation is that i need to make checkbox wrappers to have dynamic height, depense how many checkboxes is in there. I was testing plugin in jsfiddle and everything is fine in Firefox, but when i open in Chrome, same file, everything is messed up. Also when i push live same HTML, CSS and JS and open in Firefox i have same problem like in Chrome. Only difference that i saw is when i setup fixed height of `.team-wrap`  everything is fine then.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6p2q696y/2/)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is "messed up" mean?

Comment: If you open JSFiddle in Chrome, you will see that divs is one top of each other. But in Firefox everything is align like it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link to fit-columns.js is not working so your jsfiddle fails. Change it to `https://rawgit.com/metafizzy/isotope-fit-columns/master/fit-columns.js` and it should work. Also, there is not reference to `resizesContainer` anywhere in the isotope docs. Where is this from? Do you mean `isResizeBound`?

Comment: I was looking in some other examples, not official ones. Because im not familiar with this plugin, i just copy and paste it. My bad